# Eliminating off-the-road points using google apis

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-directions-api

After running my API, I get Geo-points as shown below.The blue ones are on the right route but the red ones are off the route. I need to join the points to get my final route.How to eliminate such red points?

The information I have about these points is latitude,longitude, the road on which they are on(These points have been reverse geocoded).

A,B,C are roads with different names. To filter out based on the 'road' name, we might end up eliminating the blue points on road B.

Can any of the Google APIs help? Google Directions API?

[image: route]

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I can think of (besides rolling your own distanceToPolyline algorithm manually) is using the `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge` [(documentation)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly), you can then ask all the points if they are near the route and act accordingly.

[Here's an example I made](http://jsbin.com/ubowef), try adding the markers and then hide the off-road ones (playing with the tolerance variable is also advised).

Comment: Thanks! Any links which can help me implementing these Java methods in Ruby?

Comment: @Kavya Well, the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line (assuming routes are small enough for aprox. coplanarity) is a good place to start, since you can decompose a polyline (or any route) in multiple lines, basically `set is_near as false; take two coords of the route, find the distance to the point being evaluated, if it's less than your tolerance set is_near as true, return; else pick the next coord  (pairing it with the second one chosen last time) of the route and keep iterating` if by the end of it `is_inside` is false, then it's off the road, else it's inside.

Comment: also check the other answer since it might be more useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

RouteBoxer might help.

JS implementation here- http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html

PHP server-side implementation here- http://luktek.com/Blog/2011-02-03-google-maps-routeboxer-in-php

If you are adventurous you can go through the code and try make a Ruby port.